# How can a mapping from a subspace to a space be surjective?

Tags: functional-analysis

The differentiation operator maps continously differentiable functions to continuous functions.

$$\frac{d}{dx} : C^1(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}) \to C(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$$

$C^1(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ is a subspace of $C(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$.  Naively, it seems that it should not be possible to have a surjective mapping from a smaller space to a larger space because for each vector in the larger space there must exist a unique vector in the smaller space, but a smaller space should have fewer vectors than the larger space.  Yet, the operator is surjective, as by the fundamental theorem of calculus for any $f \in C(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$, there exists $F = [x \to \int_0^xf(t)dt ] \in C^1(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$, such that $\frac{d}{dx}F = f$.

I guess this has something to do with both spaces having an infinite size, but I don't know which mathematical principle makes sense of this paradox.

Comment: Note that for an infinite set a function from a subset can be surjective

Comment: The paradox comes from using two different order relations: $X$ is "smaller" than $Y$ because $X\subset Y$ and $X$ is "smaller" than $Y$ because there is a surjection from $Y$ onto $X$. These order relations don't coincide.

Comment: Your concern is a version of [Galileo's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo's_paradox). Basically, being a  proper subset does not imply having fewer elements for infinite sets. For what does "fewer" mean?  That is a problem that is dealt with by the theory of [cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality): "fewer" means "of strictly smaller cardinality", while the examples cited as paradoxical in Galileo's paradox show that an infinite set can have the same cardinality as a proper subset.

Comment: Think of an infinite column of dwarves with the even numbers on the front of their shirts; they all turn around, and the number on their back is half the number on the front. Now they're showing the natural numbers. That's a surjective mapping from a "smaller" set to a "larger" set (which shows that "smaller" and "larger" can't be defined by injectivity and surjectivity alone).

Answer (score 2):

Both of the mentioned sets have a cardinality of ***continuum***, meaning that there exists a bijective function that maps one set into the other. It is not too difficult to reach the cardinality conclusion using ***Cantor-Bernstein-Schroeder theorem***. $Card(C(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}))\geq Card(\mathbb{R})$ and to show the opposite inequality, you can use that every continuous function is determined by its values over $\mathbb{Q}$. This way, you have a injective mapping from $C(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ to $T$, where $T$ is a set of all real sequences. The cardinality of $T$ can also be derived by using the same theorem. This way you get that $Card(C(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}))=c$ and $Card(C^1(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}))\leq Card(C(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}))=c$ since the first set is a subset of the second one. $Card(C^1(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}))\geq c$ is pretty obvious.